# Problems importing pgn to Lichess from chess.com and/or chessbase

Tags: pgn, lichess, chessbase, chess.com

[I'm writing this question so I can answer it for anyone who faces a similar problem in the future]

I am having trouble importing pgn files of my games from chess.com and from chessbase into a Lichess study.

I have exported the pgn from chess.com and chessbase (separately), and when I use the import feature on Lichess study it will only import the first move.

Answer (score 1):

There were quite a lot of things I needed to do to the pgn files to make sure they imported correctly:

1. LINE BREAKS/RETURN: chess.com and chessbase both put linebreaks/returns within their pgn files. I had to remove these. When it is a small pgn file, I just do this by hand. When it is a large file, I paste the pgn into MS Word, and use the find/replace feature and replace ^p (special character for return) with a space " ".
2. GLIPHS: If the pgn includes any classical anotated gliphs like !? or =/- or ? or ! then I needed to go through and search for character symbols like "$5" and remove them from the pgn. The longer glyphs were turned into these "$X" characters, while "!" and "?" were kepts as these characters, and I needed to remove them as well for the import to Lichess to work.
3. IMPORT IN SECTIONS: To find these errors, the way I trouble shot and searched for a solution to the problem was by importing sections of my pgn (starting at the beginning), and importing a small section with "))))))" at the end (to close all variations in the list of moves). If it worked, I made the selection of moves larger, starting at the beginning, and eventually I would find a section of moves that would break the import. I then manually looked through these moves and tried to find anything that seemed out of place or non-standard pgn moves.

I hope this is useful to someone.

Comment: [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/) can clean pgn file. Have you tried it?